# RestKit POST Send JSON doesn't content mappath/class name

Tags: ios, json, post, restkit

I'm using RestKit  to post an object to a server or to get it.
GET works great with mapping.
But POST doesn't.

Here is the form of the received JSON :

```
{"user":{"id":98,"notification":false,"id":98,"token_session":"506934689"}}
```

the problème is when a post object the sent JSON has this form :

```
{"id":98,"notification":false,"id":98,"token_session":"506934689"}
```

as you can see, "user" class name is missing! (I can't change serveur API to work with both JSON format)

here is my code if anyone can help me !

```
    RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[UserObject class]];
    [mapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"id"];
    [mapping mapKeyPath:@"token_session" toAttribute:@"token_session"];
    [mapping mapKeyPath:@"notification" toAttribute:@"notification"];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:mapping forKeyPath:@"user"];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider registerMapping:mapping withRootKeyPath:@"user"];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:[mapping inverseMapping] forClass:[UserObject class]];
//Route :
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router routeClass:[UserObject class] toResourcePath:@"user"];
```

And the post of the object :

```
RKObjectManager * manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
[manager postObject:user usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader* loader)
{
    loader.delegate = self;
}];
```

Thanks a lot.

EDIT :

I tried this :

```
RKObjectManager * manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
    [manager postObject:[CurrentSession sharedInstance].user usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader* loader)
    {
        loader.sourceObject = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[CurrentSession sharedInstance].user forKey:@"user"];
        loader.resourcePath = url;
        loader.delegate = self;
    }];
```

but the JSON so send is empty :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake !

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:mapping forKeyPath:@"user"];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider registerMapping:mapping withRootKeyPath:@"user"];
```

RestKit doesn't seems to like those both line.
I kept only the first line and the send JSON became what I expected

```
{"user":{"id":98,"notification":false,"id":98,"token_session":"506934689"}}
```